# Syntax error sql temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a simple stored procedure for a table like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TGJAE' ) IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE ##TGJAE 
GO

SELECT * 
INTO ##TGJAE 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         VOUCHER, DATAAREAID,
         TAXITEMGROUP, TAXBASEAMOUNT,
         VOUCHER, SOURCERECID
     FROM 
         TAXTRANS

GO
```

but for some reason I always get error in the SQL console:

> Incorrect syntax near 'TAXTRANS'

Can someone explain why it occurs? I check it a lot of times but I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: you need use insert Select  --  Insert into ##TGJAE   
SELECT
VOUCHER,
DATAAREAID,
TAXITEMGROUP,
TAXBASEAMOUNT,
VOUCHER,
SOURCERECID
FROM TAXTRANS  ) as t1

Comment: You're missing a **closing parenthesis** for your subquery. ....

Answer (score 2):

Here would be the easier way. Also, not sure if you purposely meant to use a global temp table or not.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TGJAE' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TGJAE 
GO


SELECT
   VOUCHER,
   DATAAREAID,
   TAXITEMGROUP,
   TAXBASEAMOUNT,
   VOUCHER,
   SOURCERECID
INTO ##TGJAE
FROM TAXTRANS 

GO
```

In your derived table example, you were missing a closing parentheses.